# Reset input filed onSubmit redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am trying to dispatch reset using ref from Redux form example given  on their site but failing in the process given is the code which I am trying to implement :

```
import {reset} from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';


const DCTForm = ({ handleSubmit, onSubmit }) => (
  <section className="chat-bg">
    <form className="chatBoxForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}  >
      <section className="input_container">
        <Input
          name="message"
          type="text"
        />
        <img src={Arrow_up} className="icon-static input_img" alt="Arrow_up" />
        <img src={Paper_plane} className="icon-static input_img_2" alt="Paper_plane" />
      </section>
    </form>
  </section>
);

DCTForm.propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func
};

DCTForm.defaultProps = {
  handleSubmit: noop,
  onSubmit: noop
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    reset:(dct)=>dispatch(reset('DCTForm'))
  }
}


export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(reduxForm({form: "DCTForm"})(DCTForm);
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use single source of truth for the input fields . instead of using refs .Use onChange event handler and this onchange event handler should set the sate attribute which contains the value of the input field .Moreover, set value attribute of the input field to be this.state.inputField (what ever input field is)

[input tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jElus.png)
[event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWiuO.png)

[State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCQgU.png)